# Flutter: OnTap and OnPressed Same Inkwell

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I have an Inkwell and an onTap that does `x` when tapped on, which is what I want. On top of that, I would like it to do `y` instead of `x` when a user presses and holds that button for a second or two.

I was wondering what functionality I can use in order to implement this, thanks in advance for any help!

```
InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.black,
          highlightColor: Colors.blue,
          onTap: pageX,
          child: Container()
```

Comment: GestureDetector longPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inkwell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) supports [onTap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse/onTap.html) and [onLongPress](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse/onLongPress.html).

Example:

```
 child: InkWell(
     onTap: (){print("onTap!")},
     onLongPress:(){print("onLongPress!")},
 }
```